# Zebble For Xamarin - Extension Installation issue with Visual Studio Community 2017 RC

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-community, xamarin-zebble, zebble

I would like to try the new `Zebble for Xamarin`.

I'm having the following problem/error:

> The extension cannot be installed to this product due to prerequisites
>   that cannot be resolved.

Notes:

- When I run the extension installer, I get: `Digital Signature:None`
- I have installed and am using Visual Studio Community 2017 RC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this source, Zebble is now compatible with Visual Studio 2017. In your post you state you're running the release client. I recommend updating to the released version. You'll also want to ensure you have Xamarin installed.

[Source](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Paymon.ZebbleforXamarin)

Answer (score 1):

Its prerequisites are:

- Xamarin extension for Visual Studio
- Universal Windows Platform tools (2.0)

Please ensure you have already installed these extensions in your Visual Studio.